# scatter plot emacs table data

Tags: emacs, elisp, spreadsheet, org-mode, emacs-ses

I'm collecting data into an emacs table, at the moment I'm using both ses-mode and org-mode.

the data in two of the columns are such that it makes sense for me to plot them as points on a Cartesian plane.

what I currently do is to collect the two columns in two vectors and to copy them in the `*Calculator*` buffer, then with `gS` and `gs` make sure I have points and no lines, then `gp`.

this opens a new window where I can see the scatter plot.

what I really would like is to have the gnuplot produce the svg (setting the terminal to `svg`) and that emacs captures that output in a buffer which I can view within emacs, and edit as text to alter the way some of the points look like.

this I can do by hand (`gD` svg, `gp`, switch to the `*Gnuplot Trail*` buffer and copy the svg source), but it's far from comfortable and I'm sure it can be automatised in elisp, and I suspect this has already been done by others staying inside of emacs.

Comment: I see that with `org-mode` I can use gnuplot-mode and opening the plot window is even easier than with `ses`, but I still don't know how to get the plot in a svg buffer.

Comment: opened an issue here: https://github.com/bruceravel/gnuplot-mode/issues/20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the question found its answer in the already mentioned [github thread](https://github.com/bruceravel/gnuplot-mode/issues/20)

Bruce added a few lines to `gnuplot-mode`, and we suggested minimal corrections to `org-mode`.

it would be fair to add a similar functionality to `ses-mode`.